# Is Khubja a wife of lord Krishna?

Tags: scripture, krishna, sanskrit, translation, garga-samhita

Consider the following story about Kubja(Trivakra), whose previous life is Surpanakha, from the scripture Garga Samhita.

> Shri Bahulashva said: What severe austerities did the maidservant
> Kubja perform in her previous birth that she so pleased Lord Krishna,
> whom even the gods cannot attain?
>
> Gazing at Lord Rama in Pancavati forest, a demonness name Shurpanakha
> fell passionately in love with Him. Seeing that Lord Rama had vowed to
> accept only one wife, and had not fallen in love with her, Ravana's
> sister Shurpanakha angrily ran to devour Sita-devi. At this Lord
> Rama's younger brother Lakshmana became angry and with a sharp-edged
> sword quickly cut away her ears and nose. Her nose cut away, she went
> to Lanka and told Ravana what had happened. Then, unhappy at heart,
> she went to Pushkara-tirtha. Wishing to get Lord Rama as her **husband**,
> for ten thousand years Shurpanakha stayed underwater and meditated on
> Lord Shiva. Pleased by this, Lord Shiva, who is the master of the
> gods and the husband of Uma, came to Pushkara-tirtha and said,
> "Ask for a boon."
>
> Shurpanakha said: You are the great master of the gods. You are
> dear to the great saints. You have the power to give all benedictions.
> Please grant me that Shri Rama will become my **husband**. Lord Shiva
> said: O demonness, please listen. At the present time your boon cannot
> be granted. In the future, at the end of Dvapara-yuga, in Mathura
> City, it will be granted to you. Of this there is no doubt. Shri
> Narada said: O noble-hearted one, in Mathura City the demonness
> Shurpanakha, who could assume any form at will, became the girl named
> Kubja.
>
> [[1-10, Chapter 11: The Stories of Kubja and Kuvalayapida, Canto 5, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_5.11:_The_Stories_of_Kubja_and_Kuvalayapida)

This story says that Surpanaka asks Siva for a boon of Rama becoming her husband. But Siva says in response that it will happen in next Dwapara yuga. Thus, it implies that Khubja is a wife of Lord Krishna.

The words they translated as husband boldify above are  *varam*, *varah*.

> Slokha 6:
>
> *tapash cakre shurpanakha varshanam ayutam jale dhyayanti try-ambakam devam shri-ramam **varam** icchati*
>
> Slokha 8:
>
> *shurpanakhovaca shri-ramo me **varo** bhuyad varam dehi satam priyah tvam deva-deva paramah sarvasam ashisham prabhuh*

But since I don't know Sanskrit. I am suspecting that translation may be not correct. Did Surpanaka really asked Siva for boon of Rama as her husband? Or is she asking for something else from Rama?

Comment: According to this story: http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/ramayana-story-hanuman-in-search-of-ramas-ring/ (don't know the actual verse it's from) Rāma incarnates many times. She probably marries Rāma (specifically Rāma) in his next birth (maybe she is long-lived enough to live until the next Tretāyuga).

Comment: Technically, it could be a previous Rāma as well.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa No, there are many other verses denying your arguments.

Comment: How could a verse denying my idea even exist, without explicitly describing who Khubja is married to? Verses could not possibly describe the uncountable forms of Rāma to account for them all.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Do you mean Rama born again in Mathura, who is not Krishna?